# CakePHP admin panel

Tags: php, cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and want an admin panel on my custom CMS for a client. Is there any way other than just linking to an admin page to each controller that I can pull views from other controllers such as users and posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a great article on creating a admin section for CakePHP 
[Creating an Admin Section with CakePHP](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/creating_an_admin_section_with_cakephp_updated)

Comment: Thanks for this link :). Here is the updated version which works on version 1.3.3 http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/cakephp_1_3_3_admin_section_template_files/

Comment: You should use Auth Component.

Comment: People who only need a VERY barebones solution can use CakePHP's default scaffolding.

Answer (score 2):

[BrowniePHP](http://browniephp.org/) could be helpful. Its a plugin for CakePHP that will save you time on backend development work.

Answer (score 1):

The better and cleaner way will be to put all your pages of admin under controllers. For example: **controllers/admin**

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PoundCake Control Panel](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bancer/). It is still in beta but may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and fasted way to add an admin panel to cakephp is to use a plugin: https://github.com/Maldicore/Admin

Answer (score 0):

This is very detailed and a great article on how to create an admin panel in cakephp - [Cakephp 3 admin panel-Cakephp admin backend](https://codingkala.blogspot.com/2018/05/cakephp-3-admin-panel-cakephp-admin.html)

Comment: While links can be useful, it is recommended to include the contents of the links as the answer will be of no use if the data on links is removed or replaced.