# CakePHP 4 Admin Panel

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am a bloody CakePHP beginner and I am wondering if there is an Admin template for CakePHP 4.x

The templates I found by Google haven't been updated sometimes for more than 7 years. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926252/cakephp-admin-panel)
is more than 11 years old and most of the links don't work anymore.

According to the DRY principle I cannot imagine I have to reinvent the wheel and start from the scratch with an Admin design, e.g. left a sidebar with the different menus for the CRUD operations and so on...

Comment: Is what you're looking for the Bake Console as described in the tutorial here https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/tutorials-and-examples/cms/tags-and-users.html?  It does a pretty good job of generating the skeleton for all the basic CRUD operations, including associations among the models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [plugin](https://github.com/maiconpinto/cakephp-adminlte-theme) and it's exactly what I was looking for. It's very nice and covers all my needs and runs under CakePHP 4.x